# Can char arrays be overwritten by longer strings in C?

Tags: c, string

Of course assuming no input will be larger than 9 chars. For example:

```
#define MAX 10
char array[MAX];
while(scanf("%s",array))!=NULL){
     //do something with the array one time,
     //now when I go back to the top of the loop I want to store a new string in the array
     //that may be longer or shorter
     //than the string that was previously in there. Ideally I want to overwrite the array
     //since I don't need the data anymore. 
}
```

Will I run into problems doing this? Is there a better way to do this? Maybe use a pointer and malloc? Thanks in advance. Remember, I am a beginner and want to learn the right way.

Comment: You can overwrite the previous string as much as you want, but `array` can never hold more than 10 `char`s. What do you really want to do with it? (Also: if you want to do it really right use `scanf("%9s", array)` or [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), so that the input won't overflow even if more than 9 `char`s are entered.)

Comment: "Of course assuming no input will be larger than 9 chars" -- You cannot reasonably assume that.

Comment: For this specific case I am assuming that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will run into problems doing this.

```
#define MAX 10
char array[MAX];
while(scanf("%s", array)) != 1) {
    /* ... */
}
```

I've changed your `!= NULL` to `!= 1` because `scanf` returns an `int` result denoting the number of items scanned, not a pointer.

`scanf` with a plain `"%s"` format will read arbitrary many characters into the array pointed to by the corresponding pointer argument. `array` is an array expression, but it "decays" into a pointer to its first element; any information about how the length of the array is lost.

You should never use a plain `"%s"` format with `scanf` (unless you have absolute control over what can appear on the program's standard input stream). There is no size you can make your array that will make it safe; if you make it 10,000 bytes, long, the user might enter 11,000 characters.

Writing past the bounds of an array like this causes *undefined behavior*. In the worst case, this could mean that your program appears to work "correctly"; the memory space past the end of the array might not be allocated for anything else, and thus might happen to appear to be usable. I call this the worst case because it means you have a bug that's very difficult to detect; traditionally, the code will fail catastrophically the first time you demonstrate it to an important customer.

You can limit the number of bytes `scanf` will write to the array by specifying a maximum length:

```
scanf("%9s", array);
```

We use `9` rather than `10` to leave room for the terminating null character `'\0'`.

If you do this, you'll need to decide what to do if there's more input than will fit in the array. Limiting the input to 9 characters avoids overflowing the array, but that still doesn't necessarily mean that you're handling longer inputs correctly. (You'll need to decide what "correctly" means in this context.)

Comment: Thank you for the well constructed answer!

Answer (score 3):

One way is you can limit the user input simply by writing:

```
scanf("%9s", array);
```

and then before setting it with a new value use memset

```
memset (array,'0',MAX_SIZE);
```

Comment: That `memset()` call is really pointless, and also broken. It's enough to set the string to empty, i.e. `array[0] = '\0';`.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is checking against `NULL`; `scanf` returns an `int` value which will either be the number of items assigned or `EOF` if there's an error, so that condition *should* read

```
int rc;
while ( ( rc = scanf( "%s", array ) ) == 1 )
{
   ...
}
if ( rc == 0 ) // nothing read
else if ( rc == EOF ) // error on read
```

although to be safe you should put an explicit length specification on it:

```
while ( ( rc = scanf( "%9s", array ) ) == 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with this. As long as the string, including the trailing null, fits in the size of the array, you can overwrite it with longer or shorter strings. There's no need to use `malloc` for this.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of characters input is **guaranteed** to be **less than** that of the amount of your character array then no, you will not run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to go with `fgets` instead of using `scanf`, if in case your input stream is multi word such as `"one two"` (within 9 chars) where `scanf` cannot read them both.

```
#define MAX 10
char array[MAX];
while(fgets(array, MAX, stdin) != NULL) { ... }
```